# Data Binding in Drop Down List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am practicing MVC 4 Razor,i want to display the list data in Dropdownlist,I have tried many options but i am not able to populate data ,i am using WCF Service
I tried using List and IEnum i am able get data in controller but how to display data in drop down list.I have pasted my code here

```
   public List<Employee> GetEmployeeList()
    {
        List<Employee> lstEmp = new List<Employee>();
        try
        {
            sqlConn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
            sqlConn.Open();
            query = "select ID,FirstName from Employee";
            sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConn);
            SqlDataReader dr = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();                
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                Employee objHeader = new Employee();
                objHeader._ID = 0;
                objHeader._FirstName = "Select Employee";
                lstEmp.Add(objHeader);                    
                while(dr.Read())
                {
                    Employee objemp = new Employee();
                    objemp._ID = (int)dr["ID"];
                    objemp._FirstName = dr["FirstName"].ToString();
                    lstEmp.Add(objemp);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                Employee objNo =new Employee();
                objNo._ID = 0;
                objNo._FirstName = "No Records Found";
                lstEmp.Add(objNo);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception err)
        {

        }
        sqlcmd.Dispose();
        sqlConn.Close();
        return lstEmp;
    }

     public ViewResult Crud()
    {
        pxy.Open();
        emplist = pxy.GetEmployeeList().ToList();          
        IEnumerable<Employee> empEnum = emplist;            
        ViewData["lstEmp"] = new SelectList(empEnum);
        pxy.Close();            
        return View();   
    }
    @Html.DropDownList("Employee", ViewData["lstEmp"] as SelectList)
```

Please Help me out.

Comment: Thanks it worked.In view i didn't changed it.

Comment: Can you please mark it as an answer..if it worked for you,..to mark it as an answer..tick the right mark on left hand side of the question so that it will be useful for others also

Answer (score 0):

**You can use the following syntax:**

```
 var dorpdownData=empEnum.Select(c=>new{c.key,c.value});
 viewdata["lstEmp"]=new selectlist(dropdowndata.asEnumerable(),"key","value");
```

**Then in your view:**

```
  @Html.DropDownList("Employee", (selectlist)ViewData["lstEmp"])
```

Hope this helps..